# How to counts row in c# with MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a Windows Form project in C # with MySQL and I wanted to know how to count all the columns of a table?

Example:

```
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id", conn);
cmd.executeNonQuery();
int usersCounter = ???
this.usersLabel.Text = $"{usersCounter} users !";
```

Where i’m write « ??? » its here i’m blocked.

Thank you for helping me, it would make me happy :)

Comment: Count the columns?  The variable says `usersCoutner` so do you mean count users (rows)?

Comment: Yes, count rows of users ;)

Comment: [SQL Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm).  Also you spelled FROM wrong

Comment: Yes, i write so fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
{
    connect.Open();
    return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To count the number of columns in your `users` table (See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)):

```
SELECT count(*) numberOfColumns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'users;
```

To count the number of rows in your `users` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) numberOfRows FROM `users`;
```

Comment: Thanks! I try this now 

Comment: No problem @cdaiga ;)

Comment: It does @VigneshKumar. See the link in my answer.